# Cryptography - How to implement MARS with ofb mode?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, block-cipher

I'm trying to find an implementation of the [**MARS**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MARS_(cipher)) algorithm with [**OFB**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Output_feedback#Output_feedback_(OFB)) operation mode in python for a project I'm working on and I can't find one that works.

I found only an implementation of OFB mode in stackoverflow

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes

plainText = b"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing e"
key = b"ANAAREMEREAAAAAA"


def ofbEnc(plainText, key):
    pos = 0
    cipherTextChunks = []
    iv = get_random_bytes(16)
    originalIV = iv
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)

    if len(plainText) % 16 != 0:
        plainText += b"1"
    while len(plainText) % 16 != 0:
        plainText += b"0"
    while pos + 16 <= len(plainText):
        toXor = cipher.encrypt(iv)
        nextPos = pos + 16
        toEnc = plainText[pos:nextPos]
        cipherText = bytes([toXor[i] ^ toEnc[i] for i in range(16)])
        cipherTextChunks.append(cipherText)
        pos += 16
        iv = toXor
    return (originalIV, cipherTextChunks)


def ofbDec(cipherTextChunks, key, iv):
    plainText = b""
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
    for chunk in cipherTextChunks:
        toXor = cipher.encrypt(iv)
        plainText += bytes([toXor[i] ^ chunk[i] for i in range(15)])
        iv = toXor
    while plainText[-1] == 48:
        plainText = plainText[0:-1]
    if plainText[-1] == 49:
        plainText = plainText[0:-1]
    return plainText


iv, result = ofbEnc(plainText, key)
print(iv, result)

plain = ofbDec(result, key, iv)
print(plain)
```

but I couldn't find **MARS** implementation in python.

Also, just to understand something, when I encrypt with **MARS** in **OFB** mode that means I encrypt each block with **MARS** algorithm and then for each block I encrypt it again with the **OFB** mode algorithm?

for example:
I'm trying to encrypt a String: 'text' with 128 bits and **MARS** will encrypt with 64 bit block size.

so I split the String to 2 blocks: b1, b2 of 64 bits each.

for each block b1, b2 I encrypt with **MARS** algorithm, we call them encb1, encb2.

then for each encrypted block encb1, encb2 I encrypt them with the **OFB** algorithm?

Comment: Why can't you use AES?

Comment: I'm rather surprised that you need to use MARS for something in 2021. It was the least-successful AES competition finalist. If you can't use AES, surely Serpent or Twofish would be better options? (They came in 2nd and 3rd place in the AES contest.) Or PRESENT for lower-resource hardware.

Comment: this is a school project, we need to create an application for secure email exchange: encryption-decryption with mars in OFB mode, secret key with EC EL-Gamel + Rabin signature.

Comment: Side note: OFB isn't an encryption algorithm, its a block cipher mode.

Comment: @SuperStormer i see, so if i look at [ofb algorithm in wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Output_feedback_(OFB)) , the mars encryption is getting as input the key and the IV right ?